# What type of character is Cheryl Blossom

Tags: character, riverdale

I am trying to figure out a way to explain Cheryl Blossom from Riverdale on Netflix.

I'd explain her personality as basically 'dead'. For example, when she is called with news she is in a dangerous place and needs to leave her response is simply

> "I understand."

And when confronting her dad she says

> "You did a bad thing daddy."

She also talks to her mom and dad using "Mommy" and "Daddy" in a very professional looking way in my opinion.

She keeps very calm during the worst events and keeps a very blank expression, is there a better word to describe this other than "dead inside". She seems to act a sort of perfect or stage how she walks very straight and such. Like even though we can see her breaking and crying at a couple points she keeps a specific type of walk and something else that I don't know how to explain.

What type of personality is this?

Examples of this

to about 7:25 and from this party

to 8:40

Comment: Well I haven't watched since season one, but she strikes me as a character that is a juxtaposition on what "fake" is. On one hand she seems emotionally far-removed and psychosomatic in her narcissim and manipulation of others. She's a spoof on a contempary "mean girl". On the other, I can see, considering Riverdale is a neo gothic reinterpretation of 1950's Archi's comics, how the character might be used to show that a "mean girl" is just a shell or an afront for how someone survives in our corrupt contempary world by prentending she doesn't feel.

Comment: I think she probably represents a cycle of victimization in a way that the other characters do not. Also, don't know if you are familiar with the concept of 'seeing how the other half lives', which is usually and can still be applied to people refering to "class", but one might see this used a bit more literally and interpersonally with Cheryl. Her  TWIN brother's death being central to the beginning of series and her, makes us see how the other half lives, when one half is dead. So some of these scenes show us she stuggles between the living and dead--the feeling and the unfelt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to quote a poem called The Lady of Shalott in my answer.

There is a term used in it which is "glassy countenance" which I think could sum up what you mean. She is detached and blank-looking, but also could be described as an *eccedentesiast*, which means someone who hides their feelings behind a curtain of indifference or a weak smile.

Also, Cheryl is stoic, which means when someone can control themselves while going through hard times, without really complaining about it.

Comment: How would you describe their style in the beginning, her and Jason. They wear lots of white and it looks very ‘clean’

Comment: @Dan Perhaps more pure and innocent before she became distraught due to her brother's death